# How to group URLs in SailsJS?

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, sails.js

I'm writing backend code for an application in SailsJS, where the API versions are maintained. Every URL starts with `/api/v1/`, but SonarQube is detecting all these URLs as duplicates.
I want to remove all these `/api/v1/` so that my code passes through SonarQube.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which rule is raising issues on this code. If it's the one about duplicate strings, then the expected fix is to use a constant and reference it instead of repeating "/api/v1/". If it's the one about hard-coded URL's then the expected fix is to off-load the URL(s) into an configuration file and read it from there. Alternately, since you're doing what you mean to do in this case, you could remove the rule from your profile or mark the issues Won't Fix.